# Ignore or prevent ESLint errors from breaking the build in a React project (create-react-project)

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-2, eslint, eslintrc

I've recently created a project with `create-react-project`.

The problem is that, while I'm developing, every time there's a problem with ESLint, the build breaks and doesn't compile the code.

Can I keep the build running while still having ESLint running and reporting errors that I will fix later?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

If you want to force ESLint to always emit warnings (that will not stop you build) instead of errors, you need to set `emitWarning: true`:

```
{
    enforce: 'pre',
    include: paths.appSrc,
    test: /\.(js|jsx|mjs)$/,
    use: [{
        loader: require.resolve('eslint-loader'),
        options: {
            formatter: eslintFormatter,
            eslintPath: require.resolve('eslint'),
            emitWarning: true,  HERE
        },
    }],
},
```

[As stated in the docs](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/eslint-loader#errors-and-warning):

> **Errors and Warning**
>
> **By default the loader will auto adjust error reporting depending on eslint errors/warnings counts.** You can still force this behavior by using `emitError` or `emitWarning` options:
>
> - **`emitError` (default: `false`)**
>
>   Loader will always return errors if this option is set to true.
> - **`emitWarning` (default: `false`)**
>
>   Loader will always return warnings if option is set to `true`. If you're using hot module replacement, you may wish to enable this in development, or else updates will be skipped when there's an eslint error.
> - ...

Comment: Can i ask in what file to put this on?

Comment: [`webpack.config.js`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/)

Answer (score 26):

just add `DISABLE_ESLINT_PLUGIN=true` in your `.env`file

cheers !

Comment: or `DISABLE_ESLINT_PLUGIN=true npm run build`

Comment: ```'DISABLE_ESLINT_PLUGIN' is not recognized as an internal or external command``` I got this, any idea ?

Comment: @KarmaBlackshaw `npm config set script-shell "C:\path\to\bash.exe"` to tell npm to use bash instead of cmd.

Answer (score 5):

since `eslint-loader` is now deprecated and `eslint-webpack-plugin` is now used in `create-react-app` check the [docs](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/eslint-webpack-plugin), I was able to solve a similar issue by adding two option to the `eslint-webpack-plugin`

after ejecting your react app, add these options to the `ESLintPlugin` options:

```
      new ESLintPlugin({
        // Plugin options
        extensions: ['js', 'mjs', 'jsx', 'ts', 'tsx'],
        formatter: require.resolve('react-dev-utils/eslintFormatter'),
        eslintPath: require.resolve('eslint'),
        context: paths.appSrc,
        failOnError: false,  <== `This one`
        emitWarning: true,  <== `And this one`
        // ESLint class options
        cwd: paths.appPath,
        resolvePluginsRelativeTo: __dirname,
        baseConfig: {
          extends: [require.resolve('eslint-config-react-app/base')],
          rules: {
            ...(!hasJsxRuntime && {
              'react/react-in-jsx-scope': 'error'
            })
          }
        }
      })
```

Comment: What if I don't want to eject?

Comment: I tried some solutions but it didn't solve the problem. one of them is to hide the warning inside the code and instead the app will only show it in the terminal, but that didn't suite me since I want the errors and warnings to appear in the code.

Answer (score 5):

For people wanting to solve this problem in 2021, you can simply set following in your .env.development file to ignore TypeScript Errors

```
TSC_COMPILE_ON_ERROR=true
```

Source: [https://create-react-app.dev/docs/advanced-configuration/#:~:text=TSC_COMPILE_ON_ERROR](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/advanced-configuration/#:%7E:text=TSC_COMPILE_ON_ERROR)

Also, to ignore ESLint errors, use craco to override `eslint-webpack-plugin` default configuration to ignore errors in development environment.

```
const eslintWebpackPlugin = require("eslint-webpack-plugin");
const process = require("process");
module.exports = {
  webpack: {
    configure: (config) => {
      config.plugins.forEach((plugin) => {
        if (plugin instanceof eslintWebpackPlugin) {
          // Ignore ESLint Errors.
          plugin.options.failOnError = process.env.NODE_ENV === "production";
        }
      });
      return config;
    },
  },
};
```

Comment: This is really a bad solution because why we use TypeScript is to throw errors at compile stage!

Comment: Which is why the solution suggests to do it when you are not in production mode

Comment: You should have compile errors at the dev stage to prevent wrong code moves on to the production stage. Don't you commit changes after development?

Comment: When you are developing things, you may want instant feedback and not stuck on solving TS errors(when you already know that the code isn't ready to be commited or pushed or ready for review). Frankly this is a preference of the developer

Answer (score 3):

I might be late for the answer but if you add
`ESLINT_NO_DEV_ERRORS=true`
in the `.env` file then the error is sorted.

*P.S:* it works with `react script 4.0.3` and above

Answer (score -2):

Ok I just commented this lines from my webpack config

```
  // {
  //   test: /\.(js|jsx|mjs)$/,
  //   enforce: 'pre',
  //   use: [
  //     {
  //       options: {
  //         formatter: eslintFormatter,
  //         eslintPath: require.resolve('eslint'),
  //
  //       },
  //       loader: require.resolve('eslint-loader'),
  //     },
  //   ],
  //   include: paths.appSrc,
  // },
```